# Dismissing Alert Dialog with custom interface using custom button

Tags: java, android, customization, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alert dialog. I am currently trying to alter the onclicklisteners for my two buttons. Previously I have used the following code.

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Nope", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
           \\code here which is not relevant to question 
      }
    });
```

However, now since the dialog has a custom view and custom buttons, I use the following approach.

```
Button confirm = (Button) windowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmbutton);
     Button cancel = (Button) windowView.findViewById(R.id.negatebutton);

     cancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v){

         }

     });
```

My question is how do I dismiss the dialog within the cancel button listener if I can't access the `dialog` variable. I want to use the `AlertDialog` I am already using and do not want a solution with a different type of dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do, is just keep a reference of the Dialog, then you can call the dismiss method. In my example, i keep the reference as a property.

```
private Dialog dialog;

@Override
public void onResume() {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LinearLayout llView = new LinearLayout(this);

    Button btnDismiss = new Button(this);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    llView.addView(btnDismiss);

    adb.setView(llView);
    dialog = adb.create();
    dialog.show();

    super.onResume();
}
```

It's important keep the reference as a property, cause the reference must be final to be accessible inside the onClick method, and since the dialog it's not created yet, you cant keep the final reference in a method variable, then keep it in a property.